# Clear all data from Django?

Tags: python, database, django

I have a Django project that uses postgresql_psycopg2 as a database. I would like to clear all data. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[django-admin.py flush](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush)